# How to initialize an instance attribute as a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, random, binary

I am trying to initialize a 10 by 5 binary matrix of random binary values as a instance attribute. At the moment I simply initialize it as a list and convert it to a numpy array in a separate function. Is there a better way to do this?

```
self.pop = np.random.randint(2, size=args)
self.pop = self.pop.astype(int)
```

This is how I do it in the function

Comment: What is your expected output? Line 1 already initilises a (10,5) matrix (numpy array) with random binary (0, 1) values, what else is needed?

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to do this so I was initializing self.pop in the __init__ method rather than a separate function. I am fairly new to coding and assumed having two self.pop initialization statements in the __init__  is considered bad? @ccl

Comment: @J French: There's no particular reason to avoid having two lines in `__init__` that deal with the same attribute. However in your case, the second line is superfluous, as the array created by `np.random.randint` by default has `dtype=int`.

Comment: Ah ok, think I've just been over complicating things. Thanks for your help. @Seb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others said, `np.random.randint` already creates an `int` array, so you're set. However if you want true binary values you can specificy the datatype as bool:

```
self.pop = np.random.randint(2, size=args, dtype=bool)
```